# Get filtered data from Google Sheets API

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api, oauth2-playground

I am using nodeJS for fetching the data from google sheet and the URL looks like :

```
var url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheet_key}/values/Sheet2!A1:J20?key=${google_API_key}`
```

From this, I am only getting the data between A1 to J20 So now I have two questions :

1. How do I get all the rows from the sheet or last 10.
2. How do I apply a structured query filter like: where name == "Himanshu"

Edited :

For question 2: what I have done is using Query Language Reference (Version 0.7) / structured queries, which is referenced by @Tanaike. This is how my URL looks 
 like now and its working as well.
`https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheets/d/${sheet_key}/gviz/tq?tq=select%20*%20where%20B%20%3D%20'Himanshu'&key=${google_API_key}`

But the issue is it's returning me the string something like this which I cant able to parse.

`google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0","status":"ok","sig":"509770406","table":{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"Response Path","type":"string"},{"id":"B","label":"Name","type":"string"}]}})`

Answer (score 3):

How about this answer?

#### A1

You can retrieve all rows using sheet name as the range as follows.

```
var url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheet_key}/values/Sheet2?key=${google_API_key}`
```

#### A2

You can use the query like `where name == "Himanshu"` using Query Language. In order to use this, please share the Spreadsheet as follows.

- On Google Drive

  - On the Spreadsheet file
  - right-click -> Share -> Advanced -> Click "change" at "Private - Only you can access"
  - Check "On Anyone with the link"
  - Click "Save"
  - At "Link to share", copy URL.

    - Retrieve file ID from `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/### file ID ###/edit?usp=sharing`

About Query Language, you can see the detail information at Query [Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage).

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit 1 :

When you want to retrieve the formatted data, please use `tqx=out:`. In your case, `tqx=out:json` is used. It seems that it's default. For example, you want csv, it's `tqx=out:csv`. Also you can use `tqx=out:html`. I think that `tqx=out:csv` may be useful for your situation.

```
https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheets/d/${sheet_key}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&tq=select%20*%20where%20B%20%3D%20'Himanshu'&key=${google_API_key}
```

### Edit 2 :

In order to retrieve JSON data of spreadsheet, please do as follows.

- On Spreadsheet

  - Click File -> Publish to the web
  - Publish as web page.

#### URL 1

You can retrieve the values of spreadsheet as JSON using the following URL.

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/${sheet_key}/od6/public/values?alt=json
```

`od6` means 1st page of spreadsheet.

#### URL 2

If you want to retrieve other pages, please confirm using the following URL.

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/${sheet_key}/public/basic?alt=json
```

#### Note :

- If error occurs when you access the URLs, please confirm whether the spreadsheet is published again.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for you such a detailed answer.

Comment: Hey I am getting content-type | application/javascript; charset=utf-8...how do I get application/json format

This is something : 
  
 google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0","status":"ok","sig":"509770406","table":{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"Response Path","type":"string"},{"id":"B","label":"Name","type":"string"}]}})

Comment: @Himanshu Teotia I'm sorry for the inconvenience and my incomplete answer. I cannot understand your current situation from your comment. Can you show us the detail information? If you can do, please add it on your question. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Himanshu Teotia Thank you for updating your question. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Still, I am not able to convert my requested data into JSON format.

Google append something like this ```/*O_o*/ ``` in requested data this cause an error.

Comment: @Himanshu Teotia I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Thanks for edited the answer. Do not you think this is something returning a bigger answer as I was expected. Does it affect my code or performance? I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Himanshu Teotia I'm sorry for the inconvenience. There is one thing I forgot for latest modification. For latest modification, Query Language cannot be used. So you are required to select one of them for your situation. I'm sorry for this situation. And I'm really sorry I couldn't answer the solution you want.