# How to update google sheets value based on SQL-like query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use google sheets' [SQL-like query functionality](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) using Java.

I figured out how to authenticate and get a [com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/Sheets.html) object. But I can't see:

1. How to run an SQL-like query.
2. How to update a value in a range. In docs I only see how to do a `select` query.

Comment: I am looking for same thing. Did you find anything on this ?

Comment: @SamarthSaxena, no. I decided to read the table and update by creating an array of `null` elements (anything not null will be updated). Basically using the other API methods and NOT using SQL-like queries.

Comment: I have found something on that maybe it can help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819927/get-filtered-data-from-google-sheets-api